# camera return small image in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I try to take photo and show it in imageView.everything is perfect but camera return small image, Thumbnail image.this is my source code

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 5;
private File mFileTemp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    takePic();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
            if(data!=null && data.getExtras()!=null)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

                if(bitmap!=null)
                {

                    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                }
            }

            break;

    }


}
private String currentDateFormat(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
    String  currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    return currentTimeStamp;
}



private void takePic() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
}





<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
```

I have no idea what is a wrong in my code.if anyone has solution help me
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to control where this image will be written. **If the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a `Bitmap` object in the [`data`] extra field**. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the `Uri` value of `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

(emphasis and reference to the proper extra name added)

You did not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and so you got a small image via the `data` extra. If you want a full-sized image, use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2016 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
    "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
  private static final String FILENAME="CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private static final String AUTHORITY=
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider";
  private static final String PHOTOS="photos";
  private File output=null;
  private Uri outputUri=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      output=new File(new File(getFilesDir(), PHOTOS), FILENAME);

      if (output.exists()) {
        output.delete();
      }
      else {
        output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }
    }
    else {
      output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }

    outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        ClipData clip=
          ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "A photo", outputUri);

        i.setClipData(clip);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
          getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
          String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
          grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
      }

      startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setDataAndType(outputUri, "image/jpeg");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.0/Camera/FileProvider))

Comment: thanks your attention,but this code starting new Activity onActivityResult.i have one question.how i can rewrite to show full image,not small, in my imageView? thanks

Comment: @Baggio: "how i can rewrite to show full image,not small, in my imageView?" -- starting with my sample code, in `onActivityResult()`, use your favorite image-loading library (e.g., Picasso) to load the image into the `ImageView`. You know where the image should be, as it is the file that you used for the `Uri` for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: i'll try it,but i still not understand why camera return small image